# Conditional rendering with routing

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, conditional-statements

I want to do conditionl rendering with routing - when condition `true` to replace to `SignUp` component and to give it a path name for the URL.

The way it is now it will keep the previous component path name (could be `/search` for instance)

 How can I do it right ?

This is how it is right now - but Signup page doesn’t have path name in the url.

```js
 return (
    <div >
      {userAccount ? (
            <SignUp />    
      ) : (
        <>
          <Header
          />
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/'>
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/search'>
                <Search
                />
              </Route>
              </Switch>
               </div> 
                 </> )}
                  </div> );
```

**NOT Working** -

This way it won't show the `SignUp` page component only blank page **with** the previous path name

```
    {userAccount ? (
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/signup'>
        <SignUp />
      </Route>
    </Switch> ) :
```

Comment: This [article](https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-protected-routes-authentication/) is relevant to what you want to achieve and is the suggested way to do it.

Comment: I know this link, I already made a Protected Route, now I don’t need it protected @Scratch'N'Purr

Comment: are you sure that when you're in `/signup` path? your code looks nothing wrong

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I even tried the Protected Route now but its not working for me here. something with the `<Switch>` I guess

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we may see better what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DrewReese I can only explain, this is the minimal code I can provide. `Header` will always show - its the navBar, `Home` and `Search` will be switched and when `userAccount ` boolean is true only `SignUp` page will show in browser (without Header).

Comment: Ok, I see. So what is the issue with the first code snippet then? It seems to do exactly as you just described to me. Are you wanting the `Signup` component to be rendered on a route, like your second snippet? What's the issue with the second snippet? Why can't you provide a minimal, ***complete***, and ***reproducible*** code example?

Comment: @DrewReese hi, The issue as I wrote in the post, is that signUp page don’t have its own path name, the url stays the same. Of course its like that because its not in a route, I tried to do it with route, but that didn’t work.

Comment: Ok, got it. I don't see an issue with the "/signup" route itself, so I suspect your issue is more to do with `userAccount` value and component rerendering. What is the app doing when you want to render the signup route and the URL isn't updating? This is where a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is helpful to us so we can see what your code is doing against the set of reproduction steps to cause the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok than I will make a codesandbox with the code so you check this issue I have. Thanks

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew, I made this sandbox with a little solution I thought of and I'll be please  glad if you can tell me if the solution is clean enough (and not ugly) and also professional - https://codesandbox.io/s/dr-n19g8?file=/src/pages/SignUp.js

Comment: Yeah, seems to work as you were wanting it to. Only comments I have is that the `Route` component won't actually consume the additional `auth` prop you are passing. You also don't need to specify the `exact` prop on every route; if you order the routes in decreasing path specificity then route matching in the `Switch` works.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks , I just didn't understand this line - " *`Route` component won't actually consume the additional auth prop passing* "  - Because it's replacing the component and not only the history path due to the Boolean (-"auth") condition.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the [Route](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) only consumes specific props. If you pass in additional props nothing is done with them. In other words `Route` ignores the `auth={auth}` prop. If you want to pass additional props to components then use the `render` prop, i.e. `<Route path="...." render={routeProps => <MyComponent {...routeProps} auth={auth} />} />`.

Comment: OK looks complex that - `{...routeProps}`, I mean how the way it works, I'll just keep it the way I did it for now.

Comment: @DrewReese I only have small issue with the rendering, but it's not showing in the codesandbox only in visual studio code.

Comment: That was only an example if you needed to pass additional props through to the component being rendered by a route. What is the issue with rendering? Can you update your question with the new issue details?

Comment: @DrewReese It’s a new issue so I’ll need new question, but I can chat with you about it. Discord or site’s chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236548/discussion-between-extrasun-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution -
I pushed `history` and used `useState()` at the same onClick fucntion.
To return back from I did the same thing only with `history.goBack()`

**App.js**

```
const [userAccount, setUserAccount] = useState(false);  

return (
    <div >
      {userAccount ? (
      <Route exact path='/signup'>
        <SignUp />
      </Route>  :
        <>
          <Header/>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/'>
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/search'>
                <Search
                />
              </Route>
              </Switch>
               </div> 
                 </> )}
                  </div> );
```

at **Header.jsx**

```js
      <button onClick={() {setUserAccount(true);
        history.push("/signup")}}>SIGN UP 
     </button>
```

**SignUp.jsx**

```js
  <button
        onClick={() => {
          setUserAccount(false);
          history.goBack(); }} >
        SIGN OUT 
 </button>
```

Thanks for everyone who helped !