# React router - protected route component isn't working

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, router

I want to show `SignUp` page component if `userAccount` boolean is true,
otherwise show the `Header` navbar.

I tried to add/remove and re-place the `<Switch>` but nothing worked.

What am I doing here wrong.
 **All is working beside the `GuardedRoute's` `Redirect`.**

**App.js**

```js
 return (
    <div className='App'>
      <GuardedRoute path='/signup' auth={userAccount}>
        <Switch>
          <SignUp/>
        </Switch>
      </GuardedRoute>
      <Header
      />
      <div className='contant-page'>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/search'>
            <Search
            />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/cart'>
            <Cart
            />
          </Route>
          <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

**Protected route**

```js
function GuardedRoute({ children, auth, path, ...rest }) {
  console.log('GuardedRoute ' + auth);
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={() => {
        return auth ? children : <Redirect to='/signup' />;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The same Protected route is working in other project but here I have a header navbar so the code and order of routes are different.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <div className='contant-page'>
    <Switch>
      <GuardedRoute exact path='/' auth={userAccount}>
        <Home />
      </GuardedRoute>
      <GuardedRoute exact path='/search' auth={userAccount}>
        <Search
        />
      </GuardedRoute>
      <GuardedRoute exact path='/cart' auth={userAccount}>
        <Cart
        />
      </GuardedRoute>
      <GuardedRoute component={PageNotFound}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</div>
```

All Routes must be inside the switch. If any protected route called and auth is false then the route will redirect to signup as example.

Comment: Why `GuardedRoute` contain all the other components ? Why the  `</Route>`  ?

Comment: What you do is: create a signup route which has a guard. if auth is false, redirect to signup. is auth is true, render children (is signup component, too)

Comment: This just doesn't work non of them will render this way. and I need the `SignUp` componet to show without the `Header`

Comment: Here is a sandbox sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-stallman-h9k33?file=/src/App.js

Comment: OK thanks, still - I have a navbar above home/search/cart. I want to show `signUp` only. I'll show my code sample

Comment: Here just the code - https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-ganguly-khb0o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark  The `SignUp` suppose to be in conditional rendering as in my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950397/conditional-rendering-with-routing?noredirect=1#comment121856960_68950397

Comment: You need to add the react-router-dom dependency to your example

Comment: Its must have all the huge project, I just wanted to show you the code. it has backend it will fall like this.

Comment: Wait..... do you wanna hide the "Navigation Items" in the Header if you not authenticated?

Comment: *To hide the Header completely